# Accepted shares won't go above 200

Tags: mining-pool-shares, guiminer

I'm new to Bitcoin mining, but I'd like to think I got things set up. I'm using guiminer, on slush's pool. For some reason, my accepted shares won't go above 200.

I have no stale shares but my accepted looks like 1597 (200).

Why is that?

[image: guiminer screenshot]

Comment: A responder will probably need more info on what miner software/hardware you are using, and what pool you are contributing your shares to. Some screenshots, even, would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using the gui miner, and im using slush's pool.

Comment: Is this something you see in GUIminer, or when logged into slush's pool? Some screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UTtEoX4.png

Comment: The number in parenthesis, is lower then the number to the left of it why is that? and why doesnt it go up further then 210?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first number is the number of shares you have solved.

The second number is the number of pieces of work that you have recieved, but haven't begun solving. If it drops to 0, you aren't mining. Every ten minutes or so, these will become obselete, and you'll need new work, so there's not much point in requesting a bunch ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, sorry for the question i'm new to the bitcoin thing.